# Retrieving Gmail messages

Tags: android, gmail

I am working on a app that will work like a Gmail notifier for Android 4.0 and above devices.

I found a few writeups on retrieving gmail emails but also came across this:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/gmail/reading-and-receiving-messages/XD0C4sw9K7U

Basically it is stated that there are no APIs currently available to get Gmail emails in Android.

I also checked the permissions and there is no Gmail read messages permission in Android Manifest.

Is it still possible? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i am also working on this. i found this link only. I think this is the latest api for gmail. u can find the sample api here https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/